# FFMPEG virtual camera on Microsoft Teams

Tags: video, ffmpeg, arch-linux, webcam, microsoft-teams

I would like to stream my monitor as the webcam input.
I do this using `sudo ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x1024 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 -vf 'hflip,scale=800:600' /dev/video0`.

I use this virtual webcam on Microsoft Teams but when there are a lot of people in the conference the video gets cropped.

Is there a fix ?

Comment: Any good reason you're using this overly complicated approach instead of just sharing content within the session? What do you mean by cropped? [Share content in a meeting in Teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-content-in-a-meeting-in-teams-fcc2bf59-aecd-4481-8f99-ce55dd836ce8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)